# Facing issue of downloading script in PHP

Tags: php, header, download

I am facing a problem of downloading script, whenever download on my project site starts, all links present in the site does not work at all. 
Once file gets downloaded completely, link starts working.

I am setting `header` and using `readfile` method of `php` for download the file. I want that file downloading should work simultaneously with users actions on the site.
I am using following code

```
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Content-Type: application/$ctype");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$docName");
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
    header("Accept Ranges: bytes"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");        
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");            
    readfile("$filename");
```

Here `filename` is name of file and `ctype` is file type.

How to resolve this?

Please let me know if anybody have solution for this.

Comment: Got any code to show us?

Comment: Many people will have a solution only if they can first understand the problem, so please help us with your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that you're missing a proper header, change content type and transfer encoding as you need

$download is the actual file  i.e. /var/www/download_images/1.jpg

$filesize is the size of the file

$filename can be any filename that you want presented to the user i.e.  homer_simpson.jpg

```
<?php
    if (file_exists($download))
    {
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Length: ". $filesize .";");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        ob_clean();
        flush();

        readfile($download);
    }
?>
```